# java. GUI. некорректно работает таймер

Tags: java, swing, gui

строчка `frame.getTextArea1().setText(" 55 ");` по таймеру пишет в поле не 55 а только пробел

```
package com.javacodegeeks.example;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Calculator {

    private JTextField resultsTxt = new JTextField(); //без этого форма GUI не видит свои поля в коде
    private JButton setBtn = new JButton("Set"); //без этого форма GUI не видит свои поля в коде
    private JPanel calculatorView = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 0)); //без этого форма GUI не видит свои поля в коде
    private JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(); //без этого форма GUI не видит свои поля в коде

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FixedCalculator frame = new FixedCalculator("Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                //System.out.println("Running....");
                frame.getTextArea1().setText(" 55 ");
            }
        }, 0, 5000);
    }
}

class FixedCalculator extends JFrame {
    private JTextField resultsTxt = new JTextField();
    private JButton setBtn = new JButton("Set");
    private JPanel calculatorView = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 0));
    private JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea();


    public FixedCalculator(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        super(title);
        setContentPane(calculatorView);
        calculatorView.add(textArea1);
        calculatorView.add(resultsTxt);
        calculatorView.add(setBtn);
        pack();

        setBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @
            Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String a, s;
                a = resultsTxt.getText();
                s = textArea1.getText();
                textArea1.setText(s + " " + a);
            }
        });
    }

    public JTextArea getTextArea1() {
        return textArea1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам был дан правильный ответ, поставьте зелёную галочку напротив ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вообще у вас всё работает верно, вы в этом можете убедиться, изменив строку `frame.getTextArea1().setText(" 55 ");` на `frame.getTextArea1().setText(frame.getTextArea1().getText() + "5");`

Вероятно, вы перепутали `textField` и `textArea`, ибо в ваш `textArea1` по таймеру послушно заполняется (прошло 15 секунд и `textArea1` заполнился уже тремя пятёрками).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. В классе `Calculator` у вас лишнее объявление ваших кнопок текстовых полей. Вы их отдельно объявляете в другом классе `FixedCalculator`, и там же и используете, поэтому комментарии *"//без этого форма GUI не видит свои поля в коде"* неверны.